# Align secondary axis origin with primary

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2010

I am interested in aligning my secondary axis such that it lines up exactly with my primary axis.

To be more clear, I want the origins to both line up at 0 at the same place, each preserving their relative scale.

I would prefer to have this be either be a VBA solution or minimizing manual work.

[image: chart]

Comment: Show us an image with the data field and your current graphic.

Comment: Due to the fact that I do not have enough reputation pts, stack overflow did not allow me to publish a graphic.

Comment: But you can put the data directly or atleast an url

Comment: good call, link added to original post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this link: http://peltiertech.com/Excel/Charts/AlignXon2Ys.html

```
' Helper Macros
Sub AlignY_PrimaryMinimum()
  AlignY 1
End Sub

Sub AlignY_PrimaryMaximum()
  AlignY 2
End Sub

Sub AlignY_SecondaryMinimum()
  AlignY 3
End Sub

Sub AlignY_SecondaryMaximum()
  AlignY 4
End Sub

' The Main Event
Sub AlignY(FreeParam As Integer)
  '' FreeParam: AXIS ALLOWED TO VARY
  '' 1: Y1 (PRI) MIN
  '' 2: Y1 (PRI) MAX
  '' 3: Y2 (SEC) MIN
  '' 4: Y2 (SEC) MAX

  Dim Y1min As Double
  Dim Y1max As Double
  Dim Y2min As Double
  Dim Y2max As Double

  With ActiveChart
    With .Axes(2, 1)
      Y1min = .MinimumScale
      Y1max = .MaximumScale
      .MinimumScaleIsAuto = False
      .MaximumScaleIsAuto = False
    End With
    With .Axes(2, 2)
      Y2min = .MinimumScale
      Y2max = .MaximumScale
      .MinimumScaleIsAuto = False
      .MaximumScaleIsAuto = False
    End With
    Select Case FreeParam
      Case 1
        If Y2max <> 0 Then _
          .Axes(2, 1).MinimumScale = Y2min * Y1max / Y2max
      Case 2
        If Y2min <> 0 Then _
          .Axes(2, 1).MaximumScale = Y1min * Y2max / Y2min
      Case 3
        If Y1max <> 0 Then _
          .Axes(2, 2).MinimumScale = Y1min * Y2max / Y1max
      Case 4
        If Y1min <> 0 Then _
          .Axes(2, 2).MaximumScale = Y2min * Y1max / Y1min
    End Select
  End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
Sub RescaleSecondaryAxis()

    Dim PriMax, PriMin
    Dim SecMax, SecMin

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("myChart").Activate
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).Select

    PriMax = ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).MaximumScale
    PriMin = ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).MinimumScale

    SecMax = PriMax 
    SecMin = PriMin 

    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).MaximumScale = SecMax
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).MinimumScale = SecMin

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your response! I actually got my answer here <http://peltiertech.com/Excel/Charts/AlignXon2Ys.html>

Comment: This gives both primary and secondary axes the exact same scales, which is probably not what the OP wanted. To align the zeros of two different scales, you need to do a little algebra so that the scales each have the same ratio of min to max.